# Loading NSMutableDictionary from URL

Tags: iphone, download

I'm currently doing this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite/mypage.php"]];
```

Which is great, apart from when the data being returned is quite large, and it appears to time out. How could I get around this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of using NSDictionary to manage downloads. I'd probably try something like:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite/mypage.php"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWintURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

Now, if data is not NULL then save to local file. Then load the dictionary using the contents of that file using the initWithContentsOfFile: method.

If you still get the timeouts you can try larger timeoutIntervals.

Comment: That sounds spot on! Can I just do something like [data saveToFile:filename] to save the data to a plist?
Thanks again

Comment: You're just using the NSData to store your download. If that's a plist then use it to dump to file and you have a plist file to work with.

Answer (score 0):

NSURLRequest (or NSMutableURLRequest) and NSURLConnection.

Answer (score 0):

In convenience methods like `initWithContentsOfURL` you have no control over things like timeouts. They are fine in my cases but it sounds like you will need to use the more low-level `NSURLConnection` and `NSURLRequest` to load data from the server. There are many examples on the net.